# Should be basic arithmetic

Tags: php, floating-point, math

For some reason this isn't storing the variable correctly giving me a value of "0" after the equation.

```
if ($power_weight  == '') {
    $power_weight = NULL;
}
else {
    $power_weight = $power_weight / 1.01387 * 2.20462262;
}
echo $power_weight;
```

When a similar equation works fine

```
if ($zero_sixty == '') {
    $zero_sixty = NULL;
}
else {
    $zero_sixty = $zero_sixty * 60 / 62;
}
echo $zero_sixty;
```

Comment: What is the value of `$power_weight` at the beginning of the code snippet? It outputs a non-zero value for me using an initial value of 40. See http://ideone.com/Uz8ux

Comment: Works with 0.1435 here: http://ideone.com/oNH7N Output: 0.312035414767

Comment: when I echo before I get its initial value, once the equation has been made I get "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the value of power_weight before this snippet? Is it a string or a float? I'd encourage you to parse it by doing floatval() on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by floating point number with limited precision

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
- to allow higher precision, try http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

Highly possible reason is using type hinting like `(int) $power_weight`

Comment: Have you done any testing to show this? See http://ideone.com/oNH7N it works as expected.